# Nomes próprios femininos de origem Portuguesa

Tags: etimologia, nomes

Queria saber alguns exemplos de nomes próprios femininos que são de origem Portuguesa?

Ou seja, os [prenomes](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prenome) [antropônimos](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antropon%C3%ADmia) cuja etimologia não tem origem em linguas estrangeiras.

Um exemplo do masculino, Viriato.

Comment: Hmm, se é como Viriato, então nome de origem *geográfica* portuguesa?

Comment: Nome próprio de pessoa (não toponímio) cuja origem não seja grega, latina, ou germânica. Um nome com origem autóctone da Lusitania. Mais ainda do que pré-Indo-Europeu ou Celta, cujo uso seja só conhecido nesta região. (Acho difícil não terem inventado nenhum nome por cá, que sejam tudo influências e produtos de outros lados.)

Comment: Seriam nomes de origem lusitana?

Comment: @ErgativeMan sim. Pelo que percebi, até agora, os nomes habitualmente são remetidos para origens atingas tipo"Indo-Europeu", ou até "proto.Indo-Europeu". Como os linguistas chegam a isso? Por comparação de fonemas por grupos linguisticos. Mas como já disse, acho difícil não haver nomes de origem Lusitana que fossem únicos de cá, ou pouco usados fora daqui ou com origem histórica mais antiga conhecida cá. Claro que difícilmente ia escapar dos fonemas habituais, mas mesmo assim algo próprio. E sim, estou a pensar Lusitano (de preferência) que não seja Celta-Ibero, nem Fenício, etc...