# Sobre a etimologia de "Vímara"

Tags: etimologia, origem-histórica, nomes, história

O primeiro [Conde de Portugal](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condado_Portucalense) foi o galego [Vímara Peres](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/V%C3%ADmara_Peres), o qual, alegadamente, deu o nome a [Guimarães](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guimar%C3%A3es) (a aos vimaranenses). A origem do nome *Vímara* é conhecida?

Comment: A etimologia dos nomes pessoais raramente é conhecida quando não tem origem romana, grega ou bíblica. Fiz [esta pergunta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/q/8055) e fui supreendido pelo facto de haver poucas explicações para os nomes pessoais, geralmente ou vão ser nomes detoponímios ou nomes próprios cognatos comuns a várias linguas europeias.